# Laravel Collection() vs collect()

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have a series of database tables that store estimating information. I am trying to return all data from all database tables when certain perimeters are set.

Collection

```
        $estimateItems = new Collection();
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getBoxVent() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getCoatings() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getCounterFlashing() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getDripEdge() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getFasteners() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getHeadwallFlashing() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getHipcap() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getIceShield() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getPipeFlashing() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getRidgecap() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getRidgeVentilation() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getSheathing() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getShingles() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getSidewallFlashing() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getSkylights() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getStarterShingle() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getTearOff() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getUnderlayment() );
    $estimateItems = $estimateItems->merge( $this->getValleyMetal() );
```

[image]

and Collect()

```
$collectedItems = collect([
        $this->getBoxVent(),
        $this->getCoatings(),
        $this->getCounterFlashing(),
        $this->getDripEdge(),
        $this->getFasteners(),
        $this->getHeadwallFlashing(),
        $this->getHipcap(),
        $this->getIceShield(),
        $this->getPipeFlashing(),
        $this->getRidgecap(),
        $this->getRidgeVentilation(),
        $this->getSheathing(),
        $this->getShingles(),
        $this->getSidewallFlashing(),
        $this->getSkylights(),
        $this->getStarterShingle(),
        $this->getTearOff(),
        $this->getUnderlayment(),
        $this->getValleyMetal(),
    ]);
```

[image]

There are only 4 database tables that have data pertaining to this "estimate" for this example. Ideally there would be 1 or all have data.

Why does Collection only return a maximum of 3, where as collect returns them all even if they're empty?

Am i doing something wrong to have the `$estimateItems = new Collection();` only return 3, when theres 4 or more in database?

Here are the queries I am using.

```
    private function getBoxVent() {
    return ProposalBoxVent::where('proposalRecordID', $this->getProposalAPI())->get();
}

private function getCoatings() {
    return ProposalCoatings::where('proposalRecordID', $this->getProposalAPI())->get();
}
```

If I use `concat` instead of `merge` I get the desired results.
[image]

Comment: If you use concat instead of merge is the result the same?

Comment: Ahhh! So using `concat` instead of `merge` gets the results I am after -- tested adding 4-5 items and they all appear. Added screenshot to the OP. Thank you.

Comment: @mrhn if you add a answer Ill accept it stating using `concat instead of merge`.

Comment: I have done it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would believe you are having problems with the merge method in `Laravel`, merge will work differently if it is an associative array or an indexed array. If it's indexed, it should work as concat. Thou if it's associtive array it will try to merge it by key value base. Therefor i believe one of your underlying methods return something wrongfully.

With that said, if you are working with indexed arrays concat is better and quicker since it don't have to check. If you want to merge `['apple' => 'green']` with `['banana' => 'yellow']` into `['apple' => 'green', 'banana' => 'yellow']` you should use merge.

In regards to your question use `concat` instead, if you are working with indexed arrays. Merge can also have bad performance in big sets.

```
$estimateItems = $estimateItems->concat($this->getBoxVent());
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more in depth what merge does vs concat? Alll my eloquent queries are the same; all returning same or similar database table structure.

Comment: I tried to update the answer, if you have any question please ask :)

Comment: Is there a better way to skin this cat than concat? I want to eliminate performance issues and try to attack it with the best methods. I am trying to compile all database tables data into a single method/array so that I can do data dumps on Materials, Labor Budgets etc.

Comment: i think that solution is fair, calling 20 or so queries will also be wonky, but concat is a way better option than merge

Answer (score 1):

What you pass to `collect()` is the array you want as the 'items' of the Collection. You are saying you want a Collection containing 18 items; it just happens to be that most of them are empty, but that doesn't matter to the array or Collection.

When you are merging you are actually merging the current items of the Collection with a new set of items. When merging it is possible that something is overwriting something else instead of adding to the Collection. Similar to how `array_merge` works as that is what is happening internally. Eloquent Collections get keyed by 'id'.

It is possible to also try to use `values` to reset the keys before merging:

```
$collection->merge($this->getValleyMetal()->values());
```

Comment: Burt theres 4 items to be merged for Collection. Why doesnt it include all the items that have data? If i put 1-2-3 they all appear, but as soon as theres 4-5-6-etc they dont add to the collection().

Comment: No; There are 3 that show in collection, but 4 database tables that have data in them. If i remove them and show individually theyll appear individually but as soon as I go over 3 collection items then it wont add. I tried to use collect() as a alternative, and get all 4 items but im after using the Collection().

Comment: are these Eloquent Collections you are merging?

Comment: Yes. I will add 1 query in OP to show what theyre all doing. (all the getxxx() are same queries from different tables.).